# Async action in MVC does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, async-await, asynccontroller

I'm trying to make an async action in my async controller. All I need to do is when I press the button in the view it give me an alert indicating that the work has been sent for getting done. and when the job get's done I can do something (For example returning a json or redirect to another view). Here is my code:

Server side:

```
    public void DoWork()
    {
       var a = MakeADelay();
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> MakeADelay()
    {
       await Task.Delay(5000);
       return  RedirectToAction("UploadComplete");
    }

    public ActionResult UploadComplete()
    {
       return View();
    }
```

and this is my client side code :

```
        $("#btnAsync").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Upload/DoWork',
            type: "post",
            success: function () {
                alert("Work in Progress!!");
            }
        });
    });
```

When this code runs all seems to execute as expected but when the server side code reaches the statement `return  RedirectToAction("UploadComplete");` it does nothing ! I think it runs in another thread or something.

what is the problem ?

Second question is what does aync action actually mean ? I never want my action to await for statements to get complete. I always want my actions to sent jobs to execution queue and return back to client, and when the jobs has completed I can notify the client in some way. How can I notify the client anyway ? with SignalR or something ?

Comment: Do you have a view for UploadComplete() Action. How are you telling that the redirecttoactino does nothing?

Comment: Of course I have a view corresponding my Redirect statement. but when it runs no redirection happens ! you can try this and let me know if is runs for you. In fact my UploadComplete() methos never gets executed. The break point never hits.

Comment: I am sorry I am not familiar with the asyc await part. SO i may not be of help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the problem ?

It's here:

```
public void DoWork()
{
   var a = MakeADelay();
}
```

What this does is start `MakeADelay` and then immediately returns to its caller, which presumably finishes creating the response and sends it.

After the delay completes, your `MakeADelay` will attempt to continue executing by calling `RedirectToAction`. However, the response for that request has already been sent, so this will most likely cause an exception (which will be ignored since you never `await` the task `a`). Or maybe it just won't do anything, but what it certainly *won't* do is go back in time and rewrite the response that was already sent.

> Second question is what does aync action actually mean ?

I have an [introduction on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find useful. I also describe on my blog that [`async` does not change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html) - you still just get one response for every request. What you're trying to do is send two responses for one request, and that just won't work.

> I always want my actions to sent jobs to execution queue and return back to client, and when the jobs has completed I can notify the client in some way. How can I notify the client anyway ? with SignalR or something ?

Then you'll need a queue. I recommend something out-of-process with persistence guarantees. E.g., an Azure queue, MSMQ, WebSphere MQ, etc.

And, yes, you could use SignalR for notification. I'd recommend that.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, you're the best in async stuff. It is exactly the answer I was waiting for