# async method does not continue when await statement returns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I'm using MVC 4 and I have the following code :

```
    public void DoWork(string connectionId)
    {
        connectionId = this.connectionId;
        var a =  MakeADelayAsync();
    }

    public async Task MakeADelayAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        var generalHubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GeneralHub>();
        generalHubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).showNotification("Completed");
    }
```

"DoWork" method is my mvc action. what I intent to do is when the action button is pressed the "DoWork" calls an async method and returns to the client immediately. when the async method has completed his job it will notify client using signalR.

The problem is in the "MakeADelayAsync" method, those two lines after await won't be called ever. It seems that the flow never continues after await.

First question is Where is the problem in "MakeADelayAsync" ?

Second question is why do I have to write a useless code of `var a =  MakeADelayAsync();` to avoid compiler warning while I'm completely aware of what I am doing? I never use "a" anyway.

Comment: Try starting the task on the threadpool. Something like `Task.Factory.StartNew(MakeADelayAsync, TaskScheduler.Default)` (taken from memory, might be wrong signature).

Comment: Alex, I appreciate your intention to help but no that was not an answer. and even if it would work it does not explain why await does not return!

Comment: The reason it is not continued is probably due to the fact that the sceduler is based around the request, and the request has ended before the await is finished. Thus it doesn't invoke the continuation after your delay (or the delay itself is canceled). Running on the ThreadPool should disconnect your methodcall from the request-context. Thats the theory at least.

Answer (score 1):

> "DoWork" method is my mvc action. what I intent to do is when the action button is pressed the "DoWork" calls an async method and returns to the client immediately. when the async method has completed his job it will notify client using signalR.

Doing this is *extremely dangerous*. I *strongly* recommend that you use a persistent queue, as I said in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17907881/263693): Azure queue, MSMQ, WebSphere MQ, etc.

However, if you insist on doing it the dangerous way, then you can use the code that I have on my blog to [execute background work on ASP.NET outside of a request context](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html):

```
public void DoWork(string connectionId)
{
    connectionId = this.connectionId;

    // This is extremely dangerous code! If ASP.NET unloads
    // your app, then MakeADelayAsync may not run to completion.
    BackgroundTaskManager.Run(() => MakeADelayAsync());
}
```

> First question is Where is the problem in "MakeADelayAsync" ?

You're executing code that is attempting to resume on the request context after the request is completed and the request context is disposed. It's the [same problem you had before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17907881/263693).

> Second question is why do I have to write a useless code of var a = MakeADelayAsync(); to avoid compiler warning while I'm completely aware of what I am doing?

The compiler warning is telling you that the code is almost certainly a mistake... and the compiler is right.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to mark your `DoWork` method as `async`?

```
public async void DoWork(string connectionId)
    {
        connectionId = this.connectionId;
        var a = MakeADelayAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I cannot mark my Action as async because it will force me to await an statement. adding async without await does not mean anything.